# Percentage increase in excel for cell in hour format

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, cell-format

I need to set a formula to calculate a percentage increase/decrease from a cell with hour format.

Now the original cell is like [mm:ss] and I need that the result to be also in tha same format.

By now I converted the original cell into seconds (numbers), increased the necessary percentage and divided the result cell by 86400. I would like to know if there was a way to avoid the intermediate step

Check the image below

[image: hour_excel]

Comment: Please share some sample data (screen shot) along with formula you have tried so far,, help us to understand the issue to fix it !!

Comment: *I would like to know if there was a way to avoid the intermediate step* Remove, what a problem? The value looks like a time is a number formatted as time. It can be multiplied directly, and the result must be formatted as time too.

Comment: You are right, sorry for the stupid question. You can close it :-(

Comment: @Ale,, check my post it skips the time to convert into Numeric seconds & directly get the increment & decremented changes in Time Format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This method solves the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Applied *Time format* on cell `L37` and `M39:M41` is `mm:ss`.
- Formula in Cell `M39`, fill down till required.

  `IF(ISBLANK(K39),"",(L$37*K39)+L$37)`

*Adjust cell reference in formula as needed,*

Comment: Glad to help you @Ale ,, keep asking ☺